# error: <EXPR>:3:1: error: use of unresolved identifier

Tags: swift, xcode, lldb

[image: Example of po not working]

Ok, this variable named iap can't be viewed. I know it's possible. Can somebody explain how viewing variables works and why it is not showing in my condition? I'm looking for understanding how this works. I've already tried the approach of trying all the options in the posts on the stack overflow and the rest of the internet. So any solution without an explanation of why it works is useless.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Solution]

If you put your breakpoint at the end, the breakpoint happens at the exit of the function, when all local variables of function are already destroyed. Add something at the end.